# If dealing with money in a float is bad, then why does money_format() do it?

Tags: php, floating-point, currency, floating-accuracy, money-format

I've been waffling on how to deal with currency display and math in PHP, and for a long time have been storing it in MySQL using the `DECIMAL` type, and using `money_format()` to format it for display on the web page. However, today I looked at the actual prototype:

```
string money_format ( string $format , float $number )
```

I'm a little confused now. All I've been told is, avoid floats for money! But here it is, the fundamental formatting function (say that five times fast), casting the input to a float. `number_format()` does the same.

So my questions are:

1. Unless I'm dealing with fractional cents or trillions of dollars (and I'm dealing with neither), should I be concerned at all about *displaying* and *storing* (but never doing math on) currency that's been cast to a float? Will I ever come close to the area of having floating point inaccuracies change my figures?
2. If the answer to #1 is that I should indeed be concerned, then why is `money_format()` built this way?

Comment: Most of the int->float conversion danger comes from then doing math with those floats. `number_format()` is simply doing a "pretty print" type conversion, so any oddball repeating decimals created by the float-ification process are highly unlikely to affect the results.

Comment: PHP is hardly the epitome of "best practices".

Comment: @OP i just noticed you said _storing_. dont store money as floats ever please. use fixed precision of some sort.

Comment: I don't, I store them in a MySQL `DECIMAL` field, which is not a float field. My consideration was, let's say I have $i, and cast it to float (via manual casting or the output from `number_format()` or what not), and then store it in the database. It will be _stored_ as a `DECIMAL`, so I'm not worried about that, so my statement was a little weird, I admit. I was more concerned about what changes might have been made to it by casting it to a float on its way around the system. That is to say, I get it out, I cast it as float, I store it back... will it be different?

Comment: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/995714)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Unless I'm dealing with fractional
> cents or trillions of dollars (and I'm
> dealing with neither), should I be
> concerned at all about displaying and
> storing (but never doing math on)
> currency that's been cast to a float?
> Will I ever come close to the area of
> having floating point inaccuracies
> change my figures?

For pure rounding/display purposes, you're safe as long as the absolute floating-point representation error is less than $0.005 (so that rounding to the nearest cent is correct).

With IEEE 754 single-precision, you're safe up to $131,072.00.  ($131,072.01 is represented as 131072.015625, which incorrectly rounds up.)

Double precision (which PHP's `float` uses) doesn't fail until $70,368,744,177,664.01 (which also has .015625 for the cents).  You have nothing to worry about.

> If the answer to #1 is that I should
> indeed be concerned, then why is
> money_format() built this way?

What type *should* it take?  PHP doesn't have a built-in decimal type.  Nor do many other languages.

Comment: String sounds like as good an idea as any. Though it's starting to sound more and more like, for purely representational issues and not math, I should be perfectly comfortable with a float. Accepted because it allayed my fears, and +1ed for the educational link. :)

Comment: You say "Doesn't fail until ..." but what about things like compounded interest? Small errors can add up.

Comment: The OP asked about displaying and storing, not math.

Comment: The link is missing.

Comment: @Nick: The question was removed as “off-topic”.  You can still see it if you have a sufficiently-high number of reputation points.