# I can't multiply decimals, in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm making a interest calculator

I go 10 * .10 * 10 and i get 0 so how do i multiply a decimal without it being 0?

my source code is

```
 def interest()
    puts "Type the original loan."
    loan = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Type the amount of interest in decimal."
    interest = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "How many years?"
    years = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Your interest is"
    puts loan * interest * years
end

interest()
```

Comment: Isn't the issue that you're using `.to_i` ?

Comment: Also, .10 is not a valid float notation.

Comment: @steenslag `".10".to_f` is valid though.

Comment: @GoshaArinich New to me!

Comment: You could also place a 0 before the decimal place and ruby will return a float of the result, i.e. 10 * 0.10 * 10 returns 10.0.  (10 * 0.10 * 10).to_i returns 10

Answer (score 6):

You've got `integer`s there, so result will be an `integer` too. You could use `'to_f` but beware, it's not good for dealing with money or anything else needing precision. Use [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead:

```
  require 'bigdecimal'
  def interest
    puts "Type the original loan."
    loan = BigDecimal(gets.chomp)
    puts "Type the amount of interest in decimal."
    interest = BigDecimal(gets.chomp)
    puts "How many years?"
    years = BigDecimal(gets.chomp) # suggested in comment, agreed with that
    puts "Your interest is"
    puts loan * interest * years
  end
```

[What's  the difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039650/ruby-bigdecimal-sanity-check-floating-point-newb)?

Comment: solved thank you, but whats the diff with BigDecimal and to_f?

Comment: I'd be using BigDecimal for the years also.

Comment: @get52: BigDecimal has _infinite_ precision, meaning that YOU can set the precision and it is stored differently than Floating point. Floating point is imprecise, because it is stored in binary format but there are certain numbers that you cannot store in a binary format, therefore they will loose precision.
Also, BigDecimal is several magnitude slower to work with, than Floating point.

Comment: @get52: added link explaining that.

Comment: also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662138/if-dealing-with-money-in-a-float-is-bad-then-why-does-money-format-do-it

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
interest = gets.chomp.to_f
```

`.to_i` changes the string to an integer. An integer is a WHOLE number.

`.to_f` is to float,  a float is a number that allows decimal places

Comment: `chomp` is superfluous.

Comment: Float is not a good way of handling financial amounts. BigDecimal is definitely the data type to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `.to_i` when you don't really want to use integers here. Integers are represented without decimal parts to them, and therefore when you call `.10.to_i` it truncates it to 0.

Consider using floats by `.to_f` instead

Comment: Float is not a good way of handling financial amounts. BigDecimal is definitely the data type to use.